# Fixing a segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, casting

I'm getting a segmentation fault, which I've narrowed down to a `for` loop in a callback function. It's strange because the program was previously working, now it's not!

```
struct debuggerth_command debuggerth_protocol[] = { /*
    * Note: These strings are NOT null-terminated. The
    * strings are 4 bytes long for memory alignment and
    * integer-cast comparisons.
    */

    { "run ", debuggerth_startprocess },
    { "stop", 0 },
    { "inp ", 0 },
    { "sig ", 0 },
    { 0, 0 }
};
```

And this is the code:

```
int debuggerth_callback (struct libwebsocket_context * context,
                    struct libwebsocket * wsi,
                    enum libwebsocket_callback_reasons reason,
                    void * user,
                    void * in,
                    size_t len){

switch (reason) {

case LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE:

    if (len < 4){
        /* send error */
        return -1;
    }

    /* Getting a segmentation fault
     * within this loop.
     */

    // I used this break to determine where the seg fault starts
    // break

    int i = 0;
    for (; debuggerth_protocol[i].cmd; i++)
        if (cmpcmd (debuggerth_protocol[i].cmd, in)) break;


    //break;

    if (!debuggerth_protocol[i].cmd){
        int byteswritten = sprintf
            (debuggerth_message,
             debuggerth_format,
             debuggerth_headers[0],
             debuggerth_errors [0]);

         libwebsocket_write (wsi, debuggerth_message,
                                      byteswritten,
                                      LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
         return -1;
    }

    break;
```

This is the string comparison macro:

```
#define cmpcmd(cmd, str) ((*(int*)(cmd)) == (*(int*)(str)))
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why is `debuggerth_protocol[i].cmd` the comparison value in your for loop? Wouldn't that be a string, when it should be a numerical value (like the number of commands inside your `debuggerth_protocol array`?

Comment: Have you checked `in != 0`?

Comment: @DyP, I didn't. I figure the library that is making the callback is checking that beforehand. I can just to be sure though.

Comment: run it with gdb or any debugger, and you will find the cause.

Comment: It was working — now it's not...What did you change?  Can you use your version control system to go back to the working code?

Comment: Is this on a platform that allows unaligned word access?  (What platform is it on?)  If not, if `in` is a pointer into an input buffer, perhaps it's sometimes not aligned?

Comment: could that be a problem? it's on ubuntu-server (arm)

Comment: @TaylorFlores yes, I think that's highly relevant; see my answer.

Comment: Yes, ARM is one of those platforms where alignment matters. See my update but basically your best bet is to optimise for readability and ditch that macro.

Comment: I found the answer, thanks @Jonothan Leffler!

Comment: Why don't you actually use an integer and assign it `'run '`? I'm not sure though if this multichar-constant feature is standart.

Comment: i'm using it for quicker parsing

Answer (score 3):

One idea: relying on the fact that your strings are exactly the size of an `int` is rather horrendous.

People often try to do clever things like that only to be badly bitten when the underlying assumptions change, such as moving to a platform where the `int` type is eight bytes.

I'd ditch that macro and rewrite it to use `strcmp` or `strncmp` <sup>(a)</sup>.

---

There's also a couple of other things to do.

First, print out (or use a debugger to examine) all variables before attempting to use them. It may be that `in` is NULL.

Or maybe you attempt to call the NULL commands like `stop` or `sig`, or even if you get a command that's not in your table and you blindly call it when `i` is equal to `4`. These particular possibilities  are in code not shown, following the loop, so it's pure, though I'd like to think educated, speculation on my part.

---

Another possibility is that you're running on an architecture that disallows unaligned access. Some architectures are optimised for accessing on specific boundaries (such as getting 32-bit values from 32-bit aligned addresses) and will run slower if you violate that alignment.

However, *some* architectures won't allow unaligned access at all, instead giving something like a BUS error if you try.

Since you've now indicated in a comment that you're using ARM, that's almost certainly the case. See [here](http://www.aleph1.co.uk/chapter-10-arm-structured-alignment-faq) for some more information.

If that's the case, it's even *more* reason to get rid of the tricky macro and use a more conventional solution.

---

<sup>(a)</sup>: You may also want to investigate the term "strict aliasing" at some point since this may technically be undefined behaviour.

Comment: yeah, I see what you mean. i tested this macro and it performed nearly twice as fast as `strcmp` so I wanted to use it in this program. I should probably be using a datatype that is guaranteed to 4 bytes. In any case, I tested it beforehand and it is 4 bytes.

Comment: 2x as fast, but it segfaults...

Comment: @Alan, good one. One of my favorite mantras is: you can't get any less optimised than "wrong" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, I printed out `in` (it's == "hello"), it's null-terminated. This is on a console, so I'm a little lost when it comes to using a debugger (I guess I'll start looking into that now).

Comment: @Taylor, if it's `hello` then it doesn't match _any_ of your commands. I would therefore ask you to provide the code immediately _after_ that loop of yours, to ascertain what it does when the loop exits and you're pointing to the `{0,0}` entry. If you blindly use it, you'll get into trouble.

Comment: I don't think it makes it past the loop (I checked using `break` statements). I added the code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Given this is running on ARM, I think your problem is that it's doing an unaligned memory access, which will either fail or be quite slow.  It is not exactly a seg fault.  [See this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119496/arm-unaligned-memory-access-workaround), and as suggested there `-Wcast-align` will probably flag it as risky.  You can turn on a software workaround but that's probably slower than just fixing it in your code.

One option would be to use `memcmp` which gcc may be able to compile down to something nearly as simple as a word read, in the case that it is aligned.

Another option, if performance is critical, is to unwind the loop into a case statement switching by the first byte of the command.  Then just check the following characters are as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at some of the changes to my code, as @Jonothan Leffler suggested. This was the change I made:

```
struct debuggerth_command {
    char * cmd;
    int (*function)(struct debuggerth_session *, char * input);
};

struct debuggerth_command {
    char cmd[4]; // changed this an array
    int (*function)(struct debuggerth_session *, char * input);
};
```

So, when I initialized the structure here:

```
struct debuggerth_command debuggerth_protocol[] = { /*
    * Note: These strings are NOT null-terminated. The
    * strings are 4 bytes long for memory alignment and
    * integer-cast comparisons.
    */

    { "run ", debuggerth_startprocess },
    { "stop", 0 },
    { "inp ", 0 },
    { "sig ", 0 },
    { 0, 0 } /* Zero used to be a pointer value,
              * but now it's the first element in a 
              * 4 byte array
              */
};
```

Which changed the evaluation of the `for` loop:

```
int i = 0;
for (; debuggerth_protocol[i].cmd; i++)
    if (cmpcmd (debuggerth_protocol[i].cmd, in)) break;
```

To always evaluate true, because `cmd` is now a valid pointer to a 4-byte array - of which, the first value is `0`.

I'll remove the macro, since it might not perform well on some architectures. But, couldn't this be fixed with the use of `C11`'s `alignas` feature?

Comment: So lesson here: had you used a standard for-loop that compared a numerical value (such as the number of commands in the array), you wouldn't not have introduced this hard to debug problem. Anyone else using your code, might easily add commands after your "end-command-array" marker, and cause your code to core.

Comment: I don't think anyone would do that. It's very easy to tell that there's a use of a null-terminating pointer. Edit: Well there is now, I changed the loop a little bit.

Comment: Actually, I'll take that advice. I changed my for loop to the traditional one, using `sizeof (commands) / sizeof (struct ..)`